# VPS server and WordPress Connection Information

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I'm using a Linode VPS server, running Debian 6, where I've just installed WordPress.

I'm having some difficulty with the connection settings that WordPress requires in order to install plugins directly from the admin panel.

I've tried using the same credentials I used to connect to the server using an FTP client: the IP address, root as username, and the root password.

I usually have no problem connecting.  My question is: is there a specific protocol for finding this connection information?

From the research I've done, one solution is to install an FTP service to the server.  I chose VSFTPD.  I've installed the service and configured the config file at /etc/vsftpd.conf in the following manner:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES Archives
connect_from_port_20=NO
chroot_local_user=YES
local_umask=022
```

From there I've attempted to create a user:

```
sudo useradd -d /path/to/your/dir -s /usr/sbin/nologin username
sudo passwd username
```

Where I'm getting stuck is the "path to directory".  Path to which directory?  Where the website resides?

Comment: What have you tried? I bet you could find the answer in the same amount of time it took to make and response to this question. =)

Comment: If you don't know your login information, ask your system administrator. Don't try logging in as root.

Answer (score 2):

This is *literally* no way we can answer this question as the credentials are unique to your VPS, just think about it for a minute, if we could help you with this then your site could be hacked by anyone right? Speak to your VPS supplier and ask them.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I should be more clear.  I'm not literally asking for the credentials.  I'm asking if I can use the root credentials to download plugins from the WordPress dashboard. Or must I create another user, or is there no way to do this from there?  Thanks.

Comment: Again, no idea, depends on VPS.

Answer (score 1):

You install WordPress plugins using WordPress account credentials if your VPS is set to run Apache as a user that can read/write the proper files. Also, the WordPress account has to be a WordPress administrator as well. If Apache is not running as a user with those privileges, WordPress will prompt you for FTP credentials that have read/write access to administrative files in the WordPress directory.

The best you could do is just give it a try and see what happens.